# Are questions about mathematicians' biographies on topic here, even if they don't relate to mathematics?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I want to ask about Fourier's life. While traveling with Napoleon, he founded an institute in Cairo called the Cairo Institute. Because I have lived in Cairo, I am just curious where that institute was. But I find scant info online, and nothing on Wikipedia, possibly because there are dozens of places that carry the name 'Cairo Institute.' Please advise if this is on-topic enough.

Comment: I can't see any reason why this should not be allowed, you should try posting it and see what happens.

Comment: Also, if you don't get an answer here, you might try posting on MathOverflow, where several people knowledgeable in the history of mathematics are regular participants.  (The worst that could happen is that your question would be closed, but even if it is, anyone with information will likely post it, either in an answer before it is closed, or in a comment --- which they can leave even if the question is closed.)

Answer (score 5):

History of mathematics should be on topic for this site.  If people want to know about whether János Bolyai really killed thirteen opponents in duels, this should be a good home for such questions.

History of mathematics is less troublesome than philosophy of mathematics, because it is less argumentative, but there seems to be general agreement that philosophy of mathematics is on topic.